# Mediation analysis - KHB ologit

Tags: stata

I'm using KHB in stata based on this paper by Kohler, Karlson and Holm: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X1101100306

When trying out the code for ordinal logistic regression, I got the same error message as this I'm author:
https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1496400-khb-method-for-mediation-analysis

I have tried the suggestion in the forum, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have experience with KHB and ologit in stata and can help me with this code?

```
forv i = 1/3 {
    quietly estate: khi ologit diabetes education || healty_diet, outcome(`i´) ape summary
}
esttab, scalars("ratio_ education Conf.-Ratio" "pct_education Conf.-Perc.")
```

I get this error:

`program error: code follows on the same line as open brace`

Comment: The title is misleading, as nothing to do with the error diagnosed.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be an issue with the syntax of your code, and not the methods you are linking to.

When using the curly brackets `{ }` to indicate the beginning and end of a loop then nothing is allowed to follow on the same line as the opening bracket `{`.

This is allowed:

```
forv i = 1/3 {
    di "`i'"
}
```

but not this:

```
forv i = 1/3 { di "`i'"
}
```

Comment: thank you for clarifying and you are correct. I don't get that error anymore, but now I got this error message: outcome () must be either a value of diabetes or #1, #2, ...

Comment: Bug solving like this is next to impossible if you do not provide a reproducible example. See here for help how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info. But based on what you share it seems like the values you put in `outcome()` is not values used in `diabetes`. Maybe that is required in this model. I do not know.

Comment: Dear @TheIceBear, I found out what was wrong with my code. It works now. Thank you for your time:)